# AH01797: client denied by server configuration

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, apache2

On an Ubuntu 16.04 server in Microsoft cloud, the following:

> AH01797: client denied by server configuration:
>   /home/projectmana/projectmana_s3/web/

../sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

```
DocumentRoot /home/projectmana/projectmana_s3/web

<Directory /home/projectmana/projectmana_s3/web>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

also:

```
projectmana@admin:~/projectmana_s3$ ls -al
total 188
drwxrwxr-x  11 projectmana www-data      4096 Feb 14 13:20 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 projectmana projectmana   4096 Feb 14 13:17 ..
drwxrwxr-x   4 projectmana www-data      4096 Feb 14 13:17 app
drwxrwxr-x   2 projectmana www-data      4096 Feb 14 13:22 bin
-rw-rw-r--   1 projectmana www-data      2969 Feb 14 13:17 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 projectmana www-data    127411 Feb 14 13:17 composer.lock
drwxrwxr-x   8 projectmana www-data      4096 Feb 14 13:17 .git
-rw-rw-r--   1 projectmana www-data       273 Feb 14 13:17 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x   2 projectmana www-data      4096 Feb 14 13:17 nbproject
-rw-rw-r--   1 projectmana www-data       978 Feb 14 13:17 phpunit.xml.dist
-rw-rw-r--   1 projectmana www-data        68 Feb 14 13:17 README.md
drwxrwxr-x   3 projectmana www-data      4096 Feb 14 13:17 src
drwxrwxr-x   2 projectmana www-data      4096 Feb 14 13:17 tests
drwxrwxrwx+  5 projectmana www-data      4096 Feb 14 13:22 var
drwxrwxr-x  26 projectmana www-data      4096 Feb 14 13:20 vendor
drwxrwxr-x   7 projectmana www-data      4096 Feb 14 13:22 web
```

and:

```
projectmana@admin:~/projectmana_s3$ ls -al ./var/cache
total 16
drwxrwxrwx+ 4 projectmana www-data 4096 Feb 14 13:24 .
drwxrwxrwx+ 5 projectmana www-data 4096 Feb 14 13:22 ..
drwxrwxrwx+ 6 projectmana www-data 4096 Feb 14 13:22 dev
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 projectmana www-data    0 Feb 14 13:17 .gitkeep
drwxrwxrwx+ 3 projectmana www-data 4096 Feb 14 13:24 prod
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needed to add: `Allow from All`!!!

Comment: Add it where and to what?

Comment: Best I can recall, it goes in `.htaccess`. Most likely in the `<Directory ...>` block.

Comment: Even more likely was in `httpd-vhosts.conf`.

Comment: I also added Allow from All and overcame the error (v2.4). But I already had "Require all granted". Doesn't this answer say they're equivalent: https://serverfault.com/questions/549517...?